# Adding Header to a Laravel view

Tags: php, html, facebook, laravel, meta-tags

im trying to share an image url on facebook , and for a preview to appear on facebook , i need to include the meta tags , "og:title", "og:type", "og:image" ,"og:url" ,and this works perfectly if i return a view ('image' , $imagename);
but then its displayed within an image tag.

i want to be Displayed as it would when u make the header as `content-type:image/jpeg`

i tried the following :

- `return response ()->file ( $imgPath , [ 'image/jpeg' ] );`
  which does the job ,  but im not refering my view here , so meta tags arent rendred..
- `return response ()->view ( 'image' , [ 'imgPame' => $imgPath ]  )->header ( 'Content-Type' , 'image/jpeg' );`
  this does it aswell but it displays an error that the image isnt found , and when i inspect it with chrome tools , i dont see the meta tags as well ..

how can i do that? , when i share a google image facebook reads its meta tags normally but wont on my url .. so no preview is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by adding a domain to my website , 
return response ()->file ( $imgPath , [ 'image/jpeg' ] );
with the domain did the job.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, please highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar or using Ctrl+K on your keyboard to nicely format and syntax highlight it!